# Incorporate V and H wheel to HID report

Tags: mouse, mousewheel, hid

I have been working with the HID reports and I have been able to compile and run a report for keyboard, 3 button mouse, and 3 button mouse with wheel (vertical only). Right now I have been trying to use the 5 buttons with vertical and horizontal wheel.

So following this

```
// Input report - 5 bytes
//
//     Byte | D7      D6      D5      D4      D3      D2      D1      D0
//    ------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
//      0   |  0       0       0    Forward  Back    Middle  Right   Left (Buttons)
//      1   |                             X
//      2   |                             Y
//      3   |                       Vertical Wheel
//      4   |                    Horizontal (Tilt) Wheel
```

Now I have this report descriptor

```
    0x05, 0x01,        // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x02,        // USAGE (Mouse)
    0xa1, 0x01,        // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x09, 0x02,        //   USAGE (Mouse)
    0xa1, 0x02,        //   COLLECTION (Logical)
    0x09, 0x01,        //     USAGE (Pointer)
    0xa1, 0x00,        //     COLLECTION (Physical)
    // ------------------------------  Buttons
    0x05, 0x09,        //       USAGE_PAGE (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,        //       USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x05,        //       USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 5)
    0x15, 0x00,        //       LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,        //       LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x75, 0x01,        //       REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x95, 0x05,        //       REPORT_COUNT (5 Buttons)
    0x81, 0x02,        //       INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------  Padding
    0x75, 0x03,        //       REPORT_SIZE (8-5buttons 3)
    0x95, 0x01,        //       REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x81, 0x03,        //       INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------  X,Y position
    0x05, 0x01,        //       USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x30,        //       USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31,        //       USAGE (Y)
    0x15, 0x81,        //       LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f,        //       LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08,        //       REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x02,        //       REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x06,        //       INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
    0xa1, 0x02,        //       COLLECTION (Logical)
    // ------------------------------  Vertical wheel res multiplier
    0x09, 0x48,        //         USAGE (Resolution Multiplier)
    0x15, 0x00,        //         LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,        //         LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x35, 0x01,        //         PHYSICAL_MINIMUM (1)
    0x45, 0x04,        //         PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM (4)
    0x75, 0x02,        //         REPORT_SIZE (2)
    0x95, 0x01,        //         REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0xa4,              //         PUSH
    0xb1, 0x02,        //         FEATURE (Data,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------  Vertical wheel
    0x09, 0x38,        //         USAGE (Wheel)
    0x15, 0x81,        //         LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f,        //         LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x35, 0x00,        //         PHYSICAL_MINIMUM (0)        - reset physical
    0x45, 0x00,        //         PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM (0)
    0x75, 0x08,        //         REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x81, 0x06,        //         INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
    0xc0,              //       END_COLLECTION
    0xa1, 0x02,        //       COLLECTION (Logical)
    // ------------------------------  Horizontal wheel res multiplier
    0x09, 0x48,        //         USAGE (Resolution Multiplier)
    0xb4,              //         POP
    0xb1, 0x02,        //         FEATURE (Data,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------  Padding for Feature report
    0x35, 0x00,        //         PHYSICAL_MINIMUM (0)        - reset physical
    0x45, 0x00,        //         PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM (0)
    0x75, 0x04,        //         REPORT_SIZE (4)
    0xb1, 0x03,        //         FEATURE (Cnst,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------  Horizontal wheel
    0x05, 0x0c,        //         USAGE_PAGE (Consumer Devices)
    0x0a, 0x38, 0x02,  //         USAGE (AC Pan)
    0x15, 0x81,        //         LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f,        //         LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08,        //         REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x81, 0x06,        //         INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
    0xc0,              //       END_COLLECTION
    0xc0,              //     END_COLLECTION
    0xc0,              //   END_COLLECTION
    0xc0               // END_COLLECTION
```

Which includes the 5 buttons, vertical and horizontal. This compiles without any issue, but I'm trying to send the following information to test if its working correctly

```
    mouseReport.buttons = 0;
    mouseReport.x = 0;
    mouseReport.y = 0;
    mouseReport.v = 1;
    mouseReport.h = 0;
```

But that 1 on the Vertical wheel byte makes my mouse, click and scroll randomly.

Could anyone tell me what am I missing? I'm using the exact same code, with a different report and 4 bytes, and the scroll works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found the issue. I was using a struct to send the byte array and it seems that my micro controller didn't like that because it was getting bad resolution, hence why the random movement and clicks. Changing it to an array of `unint8_t` fixed the issue.